# BeautifulSoup find() not finding anything

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

Here is an example that replicates the problem I am having:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

soup = BeautifulSoup('<root><td><label for="pol_nbr">Policy number<br></label></td></root>', 'html.parser')
anchor = soup.find('label', text=re.compile('Policy number'))
```

But `anchor` is none. Why is it not the `label` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the `<br>` tag, if you remove it the code works:

```
In [39]: soup = BeautifulSoup('<root><td><label for="pol_nbr">Policy number</label></td></root>', 'html.parser')

In [40]: soup.find('label', text=re.compile('Policy number'))
Out[40]: <label for="pol_nbr">Policy number</label>
```

A more reliable way may be to select using the for attribute value:

```
soup.select_one("root label[for=pol_nbr]")
```